# Remote XDebug with Aptana and Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, aptana, xdebug

Okay, I'm killing myself over this. I've been trying every single tutorial I can and still not luck. Aptana is just "waiting for XDebug Session".

I have XDebug setup on my remote server on port 9000.

```
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="jit"
```

This all seems to be correct and phpinfo makes it look correct. Now I went into Aptana to set this up and all of the tutorials involve localhost in some way. Maybe I am severely overlooking a component of xdebug (can it only debug local?). There is no way currently to have my application run locally because I am running nontraditional stack items which I don't want to install just for this.

I have setup aptana php interpreter: http://grab.by/poMm
I have setup aptana remote server using my base url and the local file document root
I have chrome xdebug helper turned on using key ECLIPSE_DBGP

Aptana is still just waiting for XDebug session. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant part of my (working) php.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

Note, there are several differences between your config and mine:

- You enclose many of your vars with quotes
- "On" should probably be "on" (without quotes)
- there is no reference to auto_start or connnect_back

Try making those changes and see if that does it for you.